# Installing Employees Sample Database on MySql 5.5.2.24?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install sample database from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/index.html. I have fresh WAMP installation on my Windows 7 machine. There is currently no password setup on MySql.

When I try to run employees.sql using command bellow it reads the file creates the database and tables, but it can't load dump files. Error given is: failed to open file load_titles.dump error 2

```
source C:\temp\employees_db\employees.sql
```

Answer (score 5):

You need put the full path to the dump files in the Employees.sql file. Edit this file on your text editor before the import.

Exemple:

'c:/user/download/load_departments.dump' instead 'load_departments.dump'.

Answer (score 2):

Below worked for me by changing (\) to (/)

```
source C:/Users/pankaj/Downloads/test_db-master/show_elapsed.sql ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install using MySQL workbench. 
click FILE>RUN SQL SCRIPT then select employees.sql

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, edit employees.sql and insert full path name for each .dump file.

So (in my case), the text becomes:

```
:
SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO';
source C:/temp/test_db-master/load_departments.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING employees' as 'INFO';
source C:/temp/test_db-master/load_employees.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_emp' as 'INFO';
source C:/temp/test_db-master/load_dept_emp.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_manager' as 'INFO';
source C:/temp/test_db-master/load_dept_manager.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING titles' as 'INFO';
source C:/temp/test_db-master/load_titles.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING salaries' as 'INFO';
source C:/temp/test_db-master/load_salaries1.dump ;
source C:/temp/test_db-master/load_salaries2.dump ;
source C:/temp/test_db-master/load_salaries3.dump ;
:
```

Second, change back slashes to forward slashes.

My command line then becomes:

```
source C:/temp/test_db-master/employees.sql`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the missing *.dump files being referenced in the employees.sql file (keep in mind that you may need to import them yourself upon successful creation of the "employees" database):

Here's the link for the missing .dump files:
[Link to missing .dump files](https://launchpad.net/test-db/employees-db-1/1.0.6/+download/employees_db-dump-files-1.0.5.tar.bz2)

```
SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO';
source load_departments.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING employees' as 'INFO';
source load_employees.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_emp' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_emp.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_manager' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_manager.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING titles' as 'INFO';
source load_titles.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING salaries' as 'INFO';
source load_salaries.dump ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit employees.sql file and insert the full path of the '*.dump' files as well as the last 'show_elapsed.sql' file
use "/" as the symbol path. Replace "\" which is by default.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to understand what a `.sql` file contains. It contains the SQL commands, hence a `.sql` file is more like a script that contains SQL commands (DDL, DML etc.).

I have downloaded a sample dataset from [here](https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db). After extracting the zip, below is the tree view of the files:

```
C:\Users\chankruze\Downloads\test_db-1.0.7.tar\test_db-1.0.7\test_db>tree /f /a
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is EA88-380A
C:.
|   Changelog
|   employees.sql
|   employees_partitioned.sql
|   employees_partitioned_5.1.sql
|   load_departments.dump
|   load_dept_emp.dump
|   load_dept_manager.dump
|   load_employees.dump
|   load_salaries1.dump
|   load_salaries2.dump
|   load_salaries3.dump
|   load_titles.dump
|   objects.sql
|   README.md
|   show_elapsed.sql
|   sql_test.sh
|   test_employees_md5.sql
|   test_employees_sha.sql
|   test_versions.sh
|
+---images
|       ._employees.jpg
|       employees.gif
|       employees.jpg
|       employees.png
|
\---sakila
        README.md
        sakila-mv-data.sql
        sakila-mv-schema.sql
```

Now coming to your issue.

Let's say I'm importing like below:

```
D:\>mysql -u root -p < C:\Users\chankruze\Downloads\test_db-1.0.7.tar\test_db-1.0.7\test_db\employees.sql
Enter password: ******
INFO
CREATING DATABASE STRUCTURE
INFO
storage engine: InnoDB
INFO
LOADING departments
ERROR at line 113: Failed to open file 'load_departments.dump', error: 2
```

Well from above log it's clear that the database structure is being created but it is giving error, for loading data from dump files, same for you right ??

Ok, time for investigation...

If you see above log mindfully, you can notice that I'm executing mysql from `D:` drive to be more generic, let's say from any other location where the extracted files are **NOT** present. See.. makes sense right ? OK.

Now if I open the `employees.sql` located at `C:\Users\chankruze\Downloads\test_db-1.0.7.tar\test_db-1.0.7\test_db` for me, from line 112 to 127 I can see there are the commands `source <xyz>.dump;` (shown below).

```sql
SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO';
source load_departments.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING employees' as 'INFO';
source load_employees.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_emp' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_emp.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_manager' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_manager.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING titles' as 'INFO';
source load_titles.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING salaries' as 'INFO';
source load_salaries1.dump ;
source load_salaries2.dump ;
source load_salaries3.dump ;

source show_elapsed.sql ;
```

These lines are responsible for loading the sample datasets (dumped from another server) to this server.

If these lines are causing the issue, it's clear that mysql is unable to locate those files.

You can notice from the tree view of the directory above that these dump files are located in the same place where `employees.sql` is (`employees.sql` and all the `*.dump` files are siblings). Hence in the sql file, those dump files are referenced relatively.

**Solutions**

We can solve this issue in 2 ways:

**1. Recommended method**

Execute the installation after navigating into the same folder form the cli. (shown below):

```
C:\Users\chankruze\Downloads\test_db-1.0.7.tar\test_db-1.0.7\test_db>mysql -u root -p < employees.sql
Enter password: ******
INFO
CREATING DATABASE STRUCTURE
INFO
storage engine: InnoDB
INFO
LOADING departments
INFO
LOADING employees
INFO
LOADING dept_emp
INFO
LOADING dept_manager
INFO
LOADING titles
INFO
LOADING salaries
data_load_time_diff
00:01:09
```

Why I recommend this ? because you just have to change the working directory and not modification is required to the `.sql` file.

**2. Alternate method**

Well, you can use absolute path in the `.sql` file as shown below:

```sql
...
SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO';
source C:/Users/chankruze/Downloads/test_db-1.0.7.tar/test_db-1.0.7/test_db/load_departments.dump ;
...
```

Note: you need to replace `\` with `/` in the full path.

This alternate approach is not encouraged, because other users who's going to use that `.sql` in their devices needs to edit it.

Hope you got both reason & it's solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem for 2 weeks now. have tried the mentioned solutions but none was helpful. I downgraded my version of workbench from version 8.0.27  to a lower version of  8.0.22 after which I was then able to run import employees data through the run script command. I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).