# MySQL syntax error for SELECT

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I received a syntax error "1064" In MySQL wamp server while trying to import a .sql file.

```
SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO';
source load_departments.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING employees' as 'INFO';
source load_employees.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_emp' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_emp.dump ;
```

The error points to:
    source load_departments.dump ;

Assuming "source load_departments.dump ; is causing the parser to show an error, then the subsequent code is *also* wrong.

I've referenced the MySQL manual verson 5.1.53, but to no avail, it looks as if the line is correct, or I am overlooking something?

Comment: What is exactly that LOADING within the quotes?

Comment: This looks like just a mysql question, is there PHP involved?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to this. Im using phpmyadmin to import a file called employees.sql. when importing i receive the 1064 error pointing to this line in the .sql file, text. I think the LOADING is referencing another dump file in the folder where the database is located

Comment: found this similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989647/installing-employees-sample-database-on-mysql-5-5-2-24

Comment: Are you running this from a PHP script or directly using mysql.exe

Comment: Are the `.dump` files in the `bin` folder?

Comment: I wonder why everyone is so curious about the "LOADING" statements. These are just normal strings. They are probably for debugging or to make it look pretty. Anyway, the error is in your load_departments.dump file. We need to see the content of it.